# ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19

Tags: android, audio, streaming, webrtc, opentok

I'm working in an android application that does audio streaming using the opentok library.
After 15/20 minutes the audio stops working, no crash, no exceptions, only this error in logs.

**ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19**

Nexus 5 android kitkat

Has anyone seen it before and can suggest a workaround?
Thank you very much

UPDATE:
It looks like the problem appears only with audio/video stream.
With audio/only streaming I get this error but the audio keeps streaming.

I have no idea what is the cause of the issue and whatdoesn thie error mean

Comment: are you streaming an mp3 audio or are you using the default publisher with publishVideo:false?

Comment: I'm using the default publisher, streaming both audio and video

Comment: a gist link with the full output of LogCat would be helpful.

Comment: this only happen with me on oneplus

Comment: I have encountered the same problem on Oculus Quest (which is also an Android device)